# How to check group memberships with kerberos single sign on in PHP

Tags: php, ldap, single-sign-on, kerberos

I have an intern website with a simple login window where you have to login before you can access the website. This login works with PHP and ldap, you have to log in with your AD credentials.

Now i have to implement Kerberos for single sign on. I have already installed the needed modules on the webserver and configured everything. Single sign on works, i can get the user with `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']`.

Not all interns are allowed to have access to the website. Because of that there are different AD user groups to handle the different access rights. With ldap its simple to check if a user is member of a specific group. But how can i do this with Kerberos? Do i still need to use ldap or has kerberos some inbuilt functions to do that?

Comment: Kerberos is an authentication protocol only. LDAP can provide both authentication and "user" attribute values.

Comment: So I still have to check the group memeberships with ldap, after I get the sso user from kerberos?

Comment: Yes. You would need to.

Comment: In that case, is there a possibility to run the ldap query with the user from kerberos? Or do i need to create some sort of service user and save the username and password to my script? Because I only get the username from Kerberos, but i need the username and password to run a ldap query.

Comment: Look into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_Security_Services_Application_Program_Interface and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPNEGO

Comment: If your server is "joined" to the AD domain then you should not need an additional service account. But that's tricky also...

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter The webserver is in the same domain as the AD. The Problem is, our policies will not allow anonymous binds.

Comment: So you need to provision a svc account for your host(s) with random pwd (in a keytab file)... That's the kind of stuff that BigCorps automate with commercial products like Centrify, and Tech boutiques automate with custom scripts.